# How to obtain bearer token for azure service principal with C#

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, bearer-token, service-principal

I need to get the bearer access token for service principal. I want to use it in C# application.

Given that I have principial Id and secret and tenant id, how can I obtain it?

EDIT:
to be more specific:
I have service principal with `client_id` and `client_secret`.
I can obtain the bearer token by azure cli using following commands

```
az login --service-principal -u client_id --tenant my_tenant_domain -p client_secret
az account set --subscription my_subscription_id
az account get-access-token
```

I would like to get the same token without using CLI, that is using Azure SDK for dot net or rest call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with following code:

```
var adSettings = new ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings
{
    AuthenticationEndpoint = new Uri(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud.AuthenticationEndpoint),
    TokenAudience = new Uri(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud.ManagementEndpoint),
    ValidateAuthority = true
};

await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(
                TenantId.Value,
                ServicePrincipalId,
                ServicePrincipalSecret,
                    adSettings,
                    TokenCache.DefaultShared);

var token = TokenCache.DefaultShared.ReadItems()
    .Where(t => t.ClientId == ServicePrincipalId)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.ExpiresOn)
    .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

The current and best way is to use the [Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) package, as it supports [Managed Service Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview), as well as Service Prinicpals.

See, for instance, [Service-to-service authentication to Azure Key Vault using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication) 
.  For other services you can follow the same process, changing the requested resource from `https://management.azure.com/`, as appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help me, as this seems to be another workflow. I will explain details in edit

Comment: See the section “Running the application using a Service Principal” in the linked doc got how to use a client Id and client secret.

Comment: There is a specific comment saying:
"This applies only to local development. When your solution is deployed to Azure, the library switches to a managed identity for authentication."